# Gmail account phone number change

Tags: gmail, account-management, account-recovery

How can I edit my contact number in Gmail account? there is no option coming to edit it. The option is coming that recovery number and send a verification code but I can't get it because my number has been changed before. And recovery email id I have already deleted. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

- go to **[https://myaccount.google.com/](https://myaccount.google.com/?utm_source=OGB&tab=wk&utm_medium=act)**
- click on **Secure account**
- select **Sign-in & recovery**

[image: l]

### _____________________________________________________________

[image: g]